# AngularJS Render huge dynamic form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

Me and my team are developing a hybrid mobile app (ionic) that basically uses SQLite as a data source to build a totally dynamic form that users then fill out. Forms are build out of sections and sections are build out of fields. Each field is a separate custom directive (like input, dropdown, etc.) that receives the setup object (ui.config) on init. The directives are totally reusaable and they carry all the information to render (template, logic, validation, special functions, etc.). But... Some of the forms that we build with this app can easily reach 50 + fields per page so we often encounter a frozen UI. We have a lot of ng-repeat loops in the form itself and we tried to replace them with quick-ng-repeat, use bindeonce and built in ::, but no serious improvement was made. UI still stucks.

Our concept of building the form is something like this:

```
1st Loop: ng-repeat form in forms
   2nd Loop: ng-repeat section in sections
      3rd Loop: field in fields => custom directive (input control)
```

I was wondering if there is a way to render Angular templates before they are compiled. Our ng-repeats that build the template layout and logic are slow, so I am thinking that the only thing that would boost things up is to create a directive that builds the dynamic HTML and then calling $parse on it.

Does anybody have any experiences with huge forms with a lot of watchers? We need an advice on how to handle this.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see why 50 fields should cause performance problems. Have built forms far larger than that using my own code as well as using angular-formly. You might want to take a look at angular-formly which has a very significant API and does a whole form with only one directive tag and a button in the html but is extremely customize-able and testable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing code outside the $digest seems the way when you have literally thousands of elements shown. It's a bit risky on the update part, you have to track down what to update - the rest is just peanuts.
You may feel the need to remove ng-mouse* or ng-click type of events too and have 1 single listener on the parent (you can still detect who's the author by the event.target).

As per another comment: 50 form elements should not slow down your page. Do some perf analysis and see who's updating your data and at what interval - id there any $digest in a loop, do you see "max 10 digest cycles reached"?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to do the analysis. It is hard to find useful information about that. We are not experiencing any $digest errors. The problem is that we have to load all the fields with validation errors, additional data (in case of dropdowns), ui logic, dependant fields (show and hide fields). All this sums up somehow to the app being unresponsive. We have about 400 watchers running. That is a lot but still Angular should handle 2000 - at least that is advertised. That is 5 times more, I don't get it.

Comment: If time allows you, try to walk through http://www.slideshare.net/dragosrusu/angularjs-overcoming-performance-issues-limits?qid=169f61af-7401-4022-a1f1-458491bba5e0&v=default&from_search=2 . In a nutshell, you should be counting EACH ng-repeat item, EACH {{ }}, EACH directive added - when you multiply these by 50 rows with 50 columns and you have 2-3 directives added, you already reached 5000-7500 watchers :)

My advise is to try to use console.timeStamp to put markers in Chrome Dev Tools timeline and to override $digest method and add some measurements there (how many times, who initited it).